# Moodle convert database Baracuda

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I'm trying to install moodle 3.3 and it does certains checks to make sure you can run it.

I'm currently stuck because it sees my database as Antelope. When trying to convert it to the newer Barracuda using [this method](https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Administration_via_command_line#Converting_InnoDB_tables_to_Barracuda), it says "no changes necessary".

So I'm stuck trying to install my new moodle.

I'm running PHP 7.0 and Mysql workbench 6.1 and mysql server 5.5.
Running windows server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your mysql settings. Edit your my.cnf file and add in [server] section

```
innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
```

Then restart MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

open your config-> my.ini and add these lines. I hope it resolves your issue.

[client]

default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]

innodb_file_format = Barracuda

innodb_file_per_table = 1

innodb_large_prefix

character-set-server = utf8mb4

collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

skip-character-set-client-handshake

[mysql]

default-character-set = utf8mb4